# Can Graphite (whisper) metrics be aliased?

Tags: alias, graphite, whisper

There is a function named alias, that I tried as given below

```
http://myhost:80/render?target=alias(my.src.metrics.endTime,"my.target.metrics.success_endTime")
```

But I want to create `my.target.metrics.success_endTime` persistent in the graphite for `my.src.metrics.endTime`. so that new values under the `my.src...` are also available via `my.target...`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

However, you can't configure persistent aliases in graphite's UI (webapp), you may create symbolic link on the filesystem, that will behave like an alias

```
./graphite/whisper/my$ ll
drwxr-xr-x  6 graphite graphite 4096 Dec 28  2016 src/

./graphite/whisper/my$ ln -s src target

./graphite/whisper/my$ ll
drwxr-xr-x  6 graphite graphite 4096 Dec 28  2016 src/
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root     root        4 Dec 28  2016 target -> src/
```

Path `my.target.*` will be findable.

Other soltuion is to use different front/dashboard UI like Grafana and make use of variables - http://docs.grafana.org/reference/templating/